# In multipart mime message how to add some info in first part of the message

Tags: java, email, multipart, mime-message

I am sending multi-part message using JavaMailSenderImpl.

I have following code to send mail.

```
  MimeMessage mimeMessage = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
        message.setSubject("Testing");
        message.setTo(getMktTemplateErrorsReportingEmailAddress());
        message.setText("Hello testing.", emailTemplate.isHtml());
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(fileName)) {
            FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(fileName);
            message.addAttachment(file.getFilename(), file);
        }
        this.mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
```

In send() method ..

```
    Object cObj = mimeMessage.getContent();
    if(cObj instanceof Multipart) {
        Multipart content = (Multipart)cObj ;
        int count = content.getCount();

        for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
            BodyPart part =  content.getBodyPart(i);
            //need to append some info if part is text.
        }
```

My understanding is first part contains message as String and second as fils (attachment). while I am seeing as first part is MimeMultipart.
eg: 
javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@79a3195f 
java.io.FileInputStream@14bedd31

Now my question is How to replace part after appending information.
eg: First part is "Hello testing.". I want to append with as some system info. for eg:  As Hello testing. IP: 192.23.22.22 . So after appending how to replace this with first part and send.

Don't know how to do this.